# Is deleting two colons in Action Script change the function?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flex4

I have action script 3 codes which is for Flex project. Now I started to convert them into HTML and need to replace one line and write in another way. I am not sure how can I do that but I will tell how I did it. But not sure if the functionality is same or not . The code block like below :

```
  private static function setObjectPropertyValue(object: Object, propertyName: String, namespaceUri: String, value: *): void {
            if (namespaceUri == null || namespaceUri == "") {
                object[propertyName] = value;
            } else {
                var ns: Namespace = new Namespace(namespaceUri);
                object.ns::[propertyName] = value;
            }
        }

        private static function getObjectPropertyValue(object: Object, propertyName: String, namespaceUri: String): * {
            if (namespaceUri == null || namespaceUri == "") {
                return object[propertyName];
            } else {
                var ns: Namespace = new Namespace(namespaceUri);
                return object.ns::[propertyName];
            }
        }
```

During the conversion process these two lines occur problem so I changed them.

Lines should be changed:

```
object.ns::[propertyName] = value;
return object.ns::[propertyName];
```

I changed them into :

```
object.ns[propertyName] = value;
    return object.ns[propertyName];
```

What I did is delete two colons. Are these deletion of colons change functionality?

Comment: Most certainly: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#name_qualifier

Comment: I have read that article and still did not get the answer whether After mine changes the code does same job as before?

Comment: Square bracket operator returns the value of the object's member by the name given in the square brackets. The **object.ns[propertyName]** notation treats **object.ns** like an object and tries to extract a value out of it. The **object.ns::[propertyName]** reads **ns** as the namespace and extracts the value out from the **object** itself. Well, that in theory.

Comment: Is there any other way to write that line in a different way ? how do you think ?